# passing string to ggplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have a function that i could apply to any object that meets a criteria, and have a nice `ggplot` scatter plot with regression line print.

However, i cannot generalise what i can do at the `REPL` with code.

so i have this working:

```
require(ggplot2)    
require(xts)
set.seed(1)
dd = xts(cbind(rnorm(10), runif(10)), order.by = Sys.Date() + 1:10)
names(dd) <- c('d1', 'd2')

gp <- ggplot(data = dd, 
             aes(x = d1, y = d2)) + 
        geom_point(shape=1) + 
        geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

But this fails

```
PointReg <- function(Xts, a=1, b=2) {
    stopifnot(is.xts(Xts), 
              ncol(Xts) >1)
    tempData <- Xts[, c(a,b)]
    gPlot <- ggplot(data = tempData, 
                aes(x = colnames(tempData)[1],
                   y = colnames(tempData)[2])) +
            geom_point(shape=1) +
            geom_smooth(method = lm)
    gPlot
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function throws an error since `aes()` tries to evaluate the argument in the column names of your data.  To be more specific, `aes()` tries to evaluate `colnames(tempData)[1]` as a column name and this column doesn't exist.

To fix this, you somehow have to tell `ggplot` that you are not passing a column name, but an expression (a string) that will resolve to a column name.

Use `aes_string()` for this.  Concretely, simply replace `aes()` with `aes_string()`. Try this:

```
PointReg <- function(Xts, a=1, b=2) {
  stopifnot(is.xts(Xts), 
            ncol(Xts) >1)
  tempData <- Xts[, c(a,b)]
  gPlot <- ggplot(data = tempData, 
                  aes_string(x = colnames(tempData)[1],
                      y = colnames(tempData)[2])) +
    geom_point(shape=1) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm)
  gPlot
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the columns using indexes.

```
> library(ggplot2)
> df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10, c=c("x"))
> ggplot(data = df, aes(x = df[,1], y = df[,2])) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `aes_string` is now deprecated, the way to use strings within ggplot is to use `!!ensym()`:

```r
d1 <- "d1"
d2 <- "d2"
ggplot(data, aes(x= !!ensym(d1), y= !!ensym(d2))) + geom_line()
```

Source: [How does enquote/quote/!! works in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65269029/how-does-enquote-quote-works-in-ggplot)