# ggplot handling quoted variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, quotes, quoting

I run into an unexpected issue in generating a `ggplot()` plot after operations done to a dataframe. I'm providing an illustrative example:

```
func <- function(){  
  library(ggplot2)
  df <- read.table(....)

  # Perform operation on df to retrieve column of interest index/number
  column.index <- regexpr(...)   
  # Now need to find variable name for this column
  var.name <- names(df)[column.index]
  # ...also need to mutate data in this column
  df[,column.index] <- df[,column.index] * 10

  # Generate plot
  plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=var.name))+geom_bar()
  print(plot)
}
```

Here ggplot will throw an error since `var.name` is quoted, eg., "mpg".
Any idea how to resolve this?

Edit: tested solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210905/passing-string-to-ggplot-function?rq=1) to no avail.

Comment: @ David: I tested `quote` as in NSE so I added the tag to give a hint about the nature of the problem.

Comment: Gotcha. Fast typing and thinking, thought I put it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `aes_string`, which allows you to pass a string name for the variable.

Comment: @ smci: thanks for the suggestion. `aes_string` would only work if `var.name` is trimmed from the quotes: ie: `var = as.name(var.name)`

Comment: found undeprecated solution here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html , `ggplot(data, aes(x= .data[[var.name]]))`

Answer (score -3):

You could use the package "dplyr" to re-name the var.name column to something generic (x) and then plot on x:

```
# also need to mutate data in this column
df[,column.index] <- df[,column.index] * 10
# ***NEW*** re-name column to generic name
df <- rename_(df, .dots=setNames(list(var.name), 'x'))
# generate plot
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x))+geom_bar()
```

Comment: and then add `+xlab(var.name)` at the end of the plotting call to re-name axis

Comment: more simple way to do the re-name step `df <- rename_(df, x  = var.name)`

Comment: This is a hack; use `aes_string()`, that's what it's for