# How does enquote/quote/!! works in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to build a function where I can pass a variable name as a string and it would return me a ggplot object.

This one works:

```r
myplot <- function(x, y) {
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x="x", y="y")) + geom_bar()
}
```

but in `ggplot` documentation:

1. It is write (I cite): "I recommend using aes_()" and
2. "All these functions are soft-deprecated. Please use tidy evaluation idioms instead"

But at that moment I figured out that I do not understand how to use `aes_` (to build an example as above, and I don't understand how to enquotation, quotation, quasiquotation means. There is a lot of literature on this in the net, but if someone could show me on this specific example how it works it probably gives me a hint to proceed from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aes_string` is deprecated.  If we are passing strings, then convert to `sym`bol and evaluate with `!!`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
myplot <- function(x, y) {
  ggplot(data, aes(x= !! rlang::sym(x), y= !! rlang::sym(y))) + geom_bar()
   }
```

---

If we pass unquoted, then use curly-curly operator`{{}}`

```
myplot <- function(x, y) {
     ggplot(data, aes(x= {{x}}, y= {{y}})) + geom_bar()
   }
```

The curly-curly operator does the `enquo` with `!!`

```
myplot <- function(x, y) {
     ggplot(data, aes(x= !! enquo(x), y= !! enquo(y))) + geom_bar()
   }
```

If we want to pass either quoted or unquoted, use `ensym`

```
myplot <- function(x, y) {
     ggplot(data, aes(x= !! ensym(x), y= !! ensym(y))) + geom_bar()
   }
```

NOTE: It is also better to have the `data` as parameter to the function

Comment: what do you mean 'pass unquoted'?

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski if you use `myplot(mpg, cyl)` if it is from `mtcars` and in the first case, it is `myplot("mpg", "cyl")`

Comment: Also see `x = .data[[x]]` instead of going the `sym()` route for strings.  @PhilippChapkovski if interesting you can see an example using that [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/#create-a-plotting-function) (slightly old; the problem with axis labels no longer exists).